# Change instance ssh admin credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs

I want to change the administrator password for my ec2 instance that is hosted on MacStadium as an external hosted instance. How do I do that?
I cannot seem to find any docs or step by step approach.

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Did you lose your ssh keypair?

Comment: Also specify the type of EC2 instance you are using, windows image or linux?

Comment: @SridharRaju no I still have the keypair and also my ssh admin password. I just want to change/rotate the ssh administration password for security purposes.

Comment: @SridharRaju it is an externally hosted mac OS server

Comment: Check the answer below, and tell me whether it suits your need or not

Comment: There are not MacOS AWS EC2 instances.  Can you tell us a bit more about what you're doing?

Comment: @stdunbar I have a priv key pair to use for access and also have an ssh username and pass. What I want to do is just ssh into the instance and change the username(administrator) password. I do not know how to do that.

Comment: @stdunbar it is hosted on MacStadium

Comment: @Myra In instance type ```passwd administrator``` it prompts for password and change it.

Answer (score 0):

- Use the reference to change the password of the user.
- [setup password for EC2 instances](https://comtechies.com/password-authentication-aws-ec2.html)
- Also check [default users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html) for different EC2 AMIs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to connect an EC2 instance to your Mac hosted at MacStadium for the purposes of password management?

Our infrastructure works slightly differently than a typical cloud and needs to be administered within the confines of macOS, when utilizing a baremetal environment.

Please feel free to open a support ticket at portal.macstadium.com with your account to further engage our dedicated support personnel with your question.

Thanks!
-Will

Answer (score 0):

MacStadium hosts dedicated Apple infrastructure, so I'm assuming the EC2 instance is reaching out to an apple node of some kind to make the above work. Then the well documented EC2 instructions won't help you much.

The command to change the password for a macOS is pretty easy: `passwd`

Changing the username is non-trivial and you must move items carefully with a reboot normally required. This would look like:

```
#/bin/bash
sudo dscl . -create /Users/[newadmin]     
sudo dscl . -passwd /Users/[newadmin] [new password].   
sudo dscl . -append /Groups/admin GroupMembership [new admin].  
sudo dscl . delete /Users/[oldadmin]
```